# Exercise 1.2.3 (From Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability

I am new to axiomatic probability and am self-learning this topic. This question is from Grimmett and Stirzaker's book.

> A conventional knock-out tournament(such as that at the Wimbledon) begins with $2^n$ competitors and has $n$ rounds. There are no play-offs for the positions $2,3,...,{2^n}-1$, and the initial table of draws is specified. Give concise description of the sample space of all possible outcomes.

I am not sure if I understood the question entirely. I would like to believe that this is much like a **binary tree** of height $n$, where pairs are formed - competitors play against each other. Each of the $n$ competitors can win the tournament. So, the set of all possible outcomes is $\Omega=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If we are only interested in the ultimate champion, that is a reasonable set of outcomes. But it is more likely that we want to record the whole history.

Comment: Hi Andre - could you elaborate...

Comment: We may  want to record who beat whom in every round, or at least (in the tree) whether the left player or the right player won.

Comment: Byron Schmuland - thank you for the edit. I will be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it is a binary tree of height $n$: to be specific it is the symmetric tree (or complete binary tree).

The draw of the tournament specifies which leaf node denotes which player.

Now the sample space of all possible results mean way of labelling the other nodes, with the condition that the lable on any internal (and the root) node should be one of the  labels from its two children.

(I am not sure one can use the terminology "labelling" when the same label is used multiple times for many nodes).